# Portable Dropbox alternative

Tags: file-synchronization, portable

I'm looking for a [dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/) (file sync via cloud) alternative which is **[portable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_application)**

Unfortunately, I cannot use [DropboxAHK](http://nionsoftware.com/dbpahk/) (portable dropbox client based on AutoHotKey) for various reasons.

According to [alternative.to](http://alternativeto.net/software/dropbox/) there are several similar programs out there. But so far I haven't found one which doesn't require an installation.

<sub>There is [TeamDrive portable](https://www.teamdrive.com/download.html) which I'm currently using. But it's conflict resolution awful and buggy</sub>

Comment: Could you expand on *why* DropboxAHK is unsuitable? Other suggestions could have the same problems.

Comment: Do you specifically want a dropbox client or would any cloud file storage provider be acceptable?

Comment: @zelanix Any storage provider is acceptable

Comment: I'm looking for the same thing! DropboxAHK seems broken now.

Answer (score 2):

What I would suggest would be to get [PortablePython](http://portablepython.com/) and add to it any of the file synchronization python apps e.g. [File Conveyor](http://fileconveyor.org/) or roll your own using the Python Dropbox API.

I even found a library & sample script that will let you do quite a lot called [SimpleDropbox](https://sergeemond.com/en/article/simpledropbox/).